# How to show toast in extjs at the top of the screen?

Tags: extjs, toast

By default Ext.toast shows messages at the bottom of the screen. However, this is not very practical because toast might not be visible when virtual keyboard is shown.

How can Ext.toast be configured to pops up at the top of the screen?

Comment: Please share code or a fiddle. Which framework? modern oder classic? In classic take a look at the docs -> properties: align, alignTarget. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.window.Toast.html#cfg-align

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aligment property:

```
Ext.toast({
    message: "Hallo Welt!",
    alignment: 'tc-tc',
    timeout: 2000
});
```

Aligment values are described [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.util.Positionable.html#method-alignTo).